# Pass param to USB ioctl

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, usb-mass-storage

I have a problem for read/write data to USB mass storage device, with 'Device or resource busy' error for below command:

```
ioctl(usbFD, USBDEVFS_CLAIMINTERFACE, &interface_num)
```

So i need to release interface before. But i don't know
How can i  pass interface_num correctly to this command:

```
ioctl(usbFD, USBDEVFS_RELEASEINTERFACE, &interface_num),
```

If it's not defined, is there any function to found this interface number.
Please help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation states:

> `USBDEVFS_RELEASEINTERFACE`
>
> This is used to release the claim usbfs made on interface, either
>   implicitly or because of a `USBDEVFS_CLAIMINTERFACE` call, before the
>   file descriptor is closed. The ioctl parameter is an integer holding
>   the number of the interface (`bInterfaceNumber` from descriptor); File
>   modification time is not updated by this request.

But it seems here "parameter is an integer" still means that a pointer to an integer should be passed, just like you're showing. If you have the descriptor, you can find the interface number.

Comment: What do you mean? I am writing a application to verify reading/writing USB device via bulk point. I only used ioctl like above but it can't work since the passing param. Please let me know to correct this?

Comment: I was wrong on the security part. Rewrote the answer.

Comment: Yes, i have read this but i still don't know the way to get bInterfaceNumber? Do you know?